# TypeScript: *.ts and *d.ts extensions

Tags: typescript

I've been realizing for some time now, some typescript files has a `.d.ts` and other ones a single `.ts` extenstion.

What are they stand for?
Which's the difference?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

These are [declaration files](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html), or sometimes they are referred to as `definition files` on the web.

I'll answer with the example that shows why you need these files.

Suppose, you have a `lib.js` library with `f` function.

```
"use strict";
function f() {
}
exports.f = f;
```

This library works well with other `js` files. For example. using from `main.js`:

```
var f = require('./lib').f;
f();
```

But you're developing in TypeScript, and you need to use this function, so in your `index.ts` you write the following:

```
import {f} from './lib';
```

But typescript compiler will give you an error:

```
Error:(1, 17) TS2307:Cannot find module './lib'.
```

This is because typescript can't read `js` files. So you need to tell a typescript compiler about your module and a function. Certainly, you don't want to rewrite the entire lib in typescript. But there is a solution - declaration files. You can use the function `f` in `index.ts` by creating a declaration file for the `lib.js` by putting the following into `lib.d.ts` file:

```
export declare function f(): void;
```

Now it will all compile correctly. If you're writing in TypeScript, these files can be generated automatically by specifying `"declaration": true,` in `tsconfig.json` file or `-d` option to `tsc`.

**When you need them**

So `d.ts` files are used alongside their JavaScript counterparts (files) during the typescript compilation time instead of the original `.ts` files if:

- you want your lib written in JavaScript to be consumed by others who
  write in TypeScript
- you want to consume the lib written in JavaScript
  in your TypeScript project

Sometimes, both `ts` and `d.ts` files are available, but a developer choses to expose only `d.ts` files. This is the approach that `angular2` team chose for their `npm` repository.

Comment: So, as far I've been able to figure out, if I'm developing a typescript library I don't need to create any `.d.ts` file, doesn't it?

Comment: If you want others who write in **javascript**, not typescript, to consume your library, you **do** need to provide `d.ts` files. But as I mention in my answer, you don't need to write them, they will be automatically generated by typescript compiler.

Comment: May be a noob question but "you want your lib written in JavaScript to be consumed by others who write in TypeScript" is opposite of "If you want others who write in javascript, not typescript, to consume your library, you do need to provide d.ts files". Aren't the declaration files meant for Typescript developers which help them consume third party JS files; mainly in the form of intellisense and also in the excellent example you provided?

Comment: Answer is partial. *.d.ts files may still be generated and consumed for pure TS libs, not only for Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

`.ts` is a TypeScript code file. `.d.ts` is a [declaration file](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html), usually used to define types for a non-TypeScript API (such as the DOM, or jQuery).

Answer (score 1):

the .d.ts files are generally to denote type definition files. Generally for libraries already existing in javascript, without the typescript source. the .ts files will be your typescript files

Answer (score 1):

A d.ts file contains only definitions of functions, props etc of various existing JavaScript libraries. (Stands for Definitely Typed Script)

a .ts file is a file which you develop on, and is converted to a js file.  (Stands for Typed Script)

Answer (score 1):

.d.ts file can not contain a code, which produces javascript during compilation. It's only for definitions (of external javascrip libraries usualy). For example, it is error to define "namespace" without "declare" modifier in .d.ts file.